# Error con la funcion mail() en php uso un servidor local Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, mail

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola buenos dias o tardes o noches donde normalmente programamos mi duda es muy sencilla alguien puede guiarme en que o cual ha sido mi error estoy tratando de enviar un correo electronico desde php y mysql usando xampp usando la funcion mail() el detalle es que cuando lo ejecuto me arroja este error alguien puede guiarme de ante mano se los agradeceria.

me estoy basando en el manual oficial de php.
y bueno este seria mi codigo el cual adapte para poder o tratar de enviar.

```
<?php 
$from = "g***************@gmail.com";
$to = ""g***************@gmail.com"";
    $sujeto ="Checa tu correo electronio";
    $mensaje ="hola esta es una prueba para ver si manda correo;                                          
    $encabezado ="From:".$from;
    mail($to,$sujeto,$mensaje,$encabezado);
```

?>

Comment: Hola, podrias incluir el codigo de lo que has intentado para ver si podemos ayudarte? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola buenos días podrías compartirnos tu código por favor

Comment: ¿Tienes un servidor de correo electrónico instalado en el mismo equipo que XAMPP? Si no lo instalaste ese es el motivo del error.

Comment: Como te dice el comentario anterior, el error es por no tener un servidor de email instalado en el equipo local.